# Xamarin custom account authenticator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement a custom account authenticator in Xamarin Droid following [this](https://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) post. I am not able to get the service running (neither the breakpoint is not hit when the application starts nor it gives any error even if i comment out the entire service. Am i missing anything here?

My androidmanifest.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
   <application>
      <service android:name="AccountAuthenticatorService" android:exported="true" android:process=":auth">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
         </intent-filter>
         <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
      </service>
   </application>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

My service is

```
[Service]
public class AccountAuthenticatorService : Service
{
    private static String TAG = "AccountAuthenticatorService";
    private static AccountAuthenticatorImpl sAccountAuthenticator = null;

    public AccountAuthenticatorService () : base()
    {
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent) {
        IBinder ret = null;
        if (intent.Action.Equals (Android.Accounts.AccountManager.ActionAuthenticatorIntent))
            ret = getAuthenticator().IBinder;
        return ret;
    }

    private AccountAuthenticatorImpl getAuthenticator() {
        if (sAccountAuthenticator == null)
            sAccountAuthenticator = new AccountAuthenticatorImpl(this);
        return sAccountAuthenticator;
    }
}
```

and I have the AccountAuthenticator implementation starting with

```
public class AccountAuthenticatorImpl : AbstractAccountAuthenticator
{
    private Context mContext;

    public AccountAuthenticatorImpl(Context context) : base(context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
```